# how to call back my app after open settings page from my app in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, appsettings

HI I am successfully open settings page from my iphone app but after that how  to come my app ? Is there any solution are manually open my app again,

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

Is the settings a bundle? (does it appear in the Settings app like Facebook, etc)

Or is this settings already in your app?

EASIEST WAY is to create a URL within your app and call that URL to bring your app.

Here is a good tutorial

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html